Video sometime causes freezing, xkill won't respond Ubuntu 24.4
I'm a newbie so please make it simple. About 40% of the time when playing videos from an external drive, the video freezes and stops everything even alt+f2 for xkill won't respond so all I can do is a hard reboot. I use vlc but this has happened online videos too, so when the video freezes there's no way of escaping the frozen video to force command prompt. Also when I play large video files of about 10 GB the players don't play smoothly for example they are pixelated and slow and out of sync. For this I use vlc, mpv and something recommend by someone here, it's just called videos on my screen but it had a different name when I downloaded it. Can anyone help? I am also using a second monitor but the video is Only displaying on the second monitor. The laptop screen only displays a photo
System Details Report

Report details

Date generated:                              2024-06-26 16:30:58

Hardware Information:

Hardware Model:                              TOSHIBA SATELLITE C855D-15W
Memory:                                      8.0 GiB
Processor:                                   AMD E1-1200 APU with Radeon™ HD Graphics × 2
Graphics:                                    AMD PALM
Disk Capacity:                               120.0 GB

Software Information:

Firmware Version:                            6.50
OS Name:                                     Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
OS Build:                                    (null)
OS Type:                                     64-bit
GNOME Version:                               46
Windowing System:                            Wayland
Kernel Version:                              Linux 6.8.0-36-generic


More details are needed to offer help. Such as.  How is the external drive attached? How is the external drive powered? The specs of the machine? The version of Ubuntu? This info added with the edit command would be a good start.

This is possibly due to a hardware issue with the discrete graphics card.

so my graphics card is not up to the job? it always worked on windows before,

Do you have swap? free will tell you and us.  If not, you need between 1xRAM and 2xRAM. Please [edit] your Question to add this information.  Do not use Add Comment.

Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story. AskUbuntu is a Question and Answer site, not a conversation site. If you have an update, [edit] your Question.  If you have a new question, see  [Ask].
